# Upgrade White Macbook to Mojave?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave

I have a technical question for this audience.  I have an older 13" white macbook (model A1342, "Mid-2010") which is currently running MacOS Sierra.  It seems to be running it fine but it is a recently wiped/reinstalled OS and I don't do much with it.  I am wondering if this machine can handle Mojave.  As for specs, it has a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor, 8 GB RAM, and a 120 GB solid state drive.  Definitely not bad for a machine of that era.  What are your thoughts?  Can this Macbook be upgraded to Mojave, and should it?  I am slightly worried that newer OS's on older machines will dog it down some.

Comment: This device can only be upgraded to High Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS Mojave is only compatible with MacBook models from [2015 or later](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201475), i.e. the 12" Retina models. (There were no Macs just branded *MacBook* released between 2010 and 2015; Mojave supports MacBook Air and MacBook Pro models back to 2012.)

The latest macOS that will run on [your MacBook](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-white-13-polycarbonate-unibody-mid-2010-specs.html) is 10.13 High Sierra.

Only you can decide whether the performance will be OK for your usage, so I would suggest you try installing High Sierra and see how you get on.